# how to get the site to not collapse with css

Tags: html, css

is there a way to change the CSS on this, so when the window is resized the text doesnt collapse and a horizontal scroll bar is created? I tried adding a wrapper div and setting the width on it, but then the full background effect with the images and colors collapses as well.

http://2012dminominees.edulence.com/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "collapse".  The page looks fine to me and when I resize the browser window, a horizontal scroll bar becomes visible if needed.  I'm sing Firefox 10.0.2 on Mac OSX

Comment: You could set `overflow-x: hidden` on the body, but the image/text in the middle isn't centered.

Comment: the ribbon on the top right covers the text if resized small enough... the whole thing moves to the left instead of staying centered. and the horizontal scroll bar only comes if resized small enough

Comment: the image/text in the middle is a background image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of changes in your CSS/HTML:

I'd add the ribbon inside the .inner div

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="./nominee hub_files/DMI-logo.png" height="140px" width="140px">
        <h1>nominee hub</h1>        
        <div id="ribbon">
            <img src="./nominee hub_files/ribbon.png">
        </div>
    </div><!--END inner -->
</div><!--END header -->
```

You're on the right track, just a couple tweaks:

Keeps ribbon in the right place:

```
.inner {
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 1050px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Overlap issues:

```
#ribbon {
    top:0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    z-index:0;
}

#header h1 {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 72px;
    margin-left: 197px;
    color: #f8f9fa;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Keeps middle image centered:

```
#main {
    padding-top: 369px;
    padding-bottom: 27px;
    background: url('main-bg.png') 50% -1px no-repeat;
}
```

Basically, this keeps the content of your site with a width of 1050px, and eliminates the bars when the browser window is wider than that, while keeping the page looking the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `min-width` and `min-height` properties in CSS. This will create scrollbars as necessary when the window is resized below these limits.

Comment: on which elements? i've set it for the body, wrapper and inner and it doesn't work

Comment: I think the problem is on `<div id="ribbon">`.

Comment: It is set to position absolute. Perhaps try just floating it right, and remove the position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set your site up using fixed widths instead of variable. Then it will never collapse beyond what you want it to.